# JButton toggle method not working as expected

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, jbutton

Here's what I'm trying to do: Create a `JButton`, and when clicked, its `setText()` will change to `Happy`, and then when clicked again, its `setText()` will change to `Sad`. Basically, I want it to toggle between `Happy` and `Sad` when clicked. (Sorry for the awful explanation)

The issue is that the button changes text only the **first** time I click it (from `Happy` to `Sad`). When clicked again, it does not change text.

This is my code for the toggle method:

```
boolean toggleButton = true;
JButton button = new JButton("Sad");

public void changeButtonText() {
    if(toggleButton = true) {
        toggleButton = false;
        button.setText("Happy");
    } else if (toggleButton = false) {
        toggleButton = true;
        button.setText("Sad");
    }
}
```

Then, I have my ActionListener:

```
class ButtonListener implements ActionListener {
    public void actionPerformed (ActionEvent event) {
        changeButtonText();
    }
}

button.addActionListener (new ButtonListener());
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You're assigning values to `toggleButton` in your `if` statements. Please use `==` or, better yet, `if (toggleButton)` and `if (!toggleButton)`. And why do you need `else if` for boolean anyway?

```
public void changeButtonText() {
   toggleButton = !toggleButton;
   button.setText(toggleButton ? "Happy" : "Sad");
}
```